# Vuetify - Search function in table that jumps to the found row

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have 2 Vuetify data tables without pagination. Every row of the second one got exactly one parent in the first one. If I click on one of those entries in the second one, I want to search for the parent and jump to that row. All I found for now is filtering, but I only want to have that row on top of my table.
Is something like this possible?

Comment: Can you accompany your question with the code please

Comment: No sorry, can't publish it here..
I only want to know if something like this is possible and if somebody else did something similar in the past

Answer (score 1):

We can't really help you without code, even if i've seen that you can't, it should be cool if you could modify some parts of your code like variables and datas ...

However, i'll try to do my best to explain

What you have to do is to reorder your data array binded on your table depending on a given id (or other data) to identify it.

I made a similar exemple of your needs, but i repeat i can't really be exhausitve :

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <listone :list="listOne" :toggled="toggledParent"></listone>

    <listtwo :list="listTwo" v-model="toggledParent"></listtwo>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    toggledParent: 0,
    listOne: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "parent1",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "parent2",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "parent3",
      },
    ],
    listTwo: [
      {
        title: "title1",
        parent: 3,
      },
      {
        title: "title2",
        parent: 1,
      },
      {
        title: "title3",
        parent: 2,
      },
    ],
  }),
  components: {
    listone: () => import("@/components/listone"),
    listtwo: () => import("@/components/listtwo"),
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>
```

ListOne component :

```
<template>
  <div class="list">
    <a v-for="item in treatedList" :key="item.title">
      {{ item.title }}
    </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "listone",
  props: {
    list: Array,
    toggled: Number,
  },
  computed: {
    treatedList: function () {
      let tmp = this.list;
      let $this = this
      return tmp.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.id === $this.toggled ? -1 : b.id === $this.toggled ? 1 : 0;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.list > a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

ListTwo component :

```
<template>
  <div class="list">
      <a 
        v-for="item in list" 
        :key="item.title" 
        @click="$emit('input', item.parent)">
      {{ item.title }}
    </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "listtwo",
  props: {
    list: Array,
    toggledParent: Number
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.list > a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Try it and say me it helps you as wanted

Demo on codesandbox.io : https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-thunder-zo8vn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Hey your example doesn't do anything for me..
So I explain a bit more what I have now..
I have 2 tables without pagination with virtual scroll. Lets say one with adresses and one with persons who live there. They're connected with an id.
I can filter and sort both of the tables.
Now if I click on a person the address table should jump to that row and mark it without new sorting or anything.
A bit like the answer of procoib, but the click is the search and I don't want to reorder anything.

Answer (score 0):

So without knowing what your data looks like i'll use a standard array of objects without meta data.

What you could do, is use the sort function inside of computed property like below, this will re-organize your list every time you match or filter the list.

(Note: This re-arranges your entire list every time)

Here is a really basic example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   search: 'Bananas',
   tableData: [
   {
    item: "Cherries",
    price: 3.99,
    type: "Fruit"
   },
   {
    item: "Chicken",
    price: 6.99,
    type: "Meat"
   },
   {
    item: "Bananas",
    price: 1.99,
    type: "Fruit"
   },
   {
    item: "Cola",
    price: 0.99,
    type: "Drink"
   },
   {
    item: "Coffee",
    price: 2.99,
    type: "Drink"
   },
   ]
  },
  computed: {
    getTableData: function() {
      return this.tableData.sort((x,y) => { return x.item == this.search ? -1 : y.item == this.search ? 1 : 0; });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  width:50%;
}
table tr {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr td {
  padding: 10px;
}
.firstRow {
  background: green;
  color:white;
}
.searchBar {
  padding:20px;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="searchBar">
Search <input type="text" v-model="search">
</div>
  <table>
  
  <tr class="firstRow"><td>Item</td> <td>Price</td> <td>Type</td></tr>
    <tr v-for="(product, index) in getTableData" :key="index">
      <td>{{product.item}}</td>
      <td>{{product.type}}</td>
      <td>{{product.price}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this goes to the right direction. Your search feature would be my click on a row of the other table. But I don't want to rearrange, I only want to jump to that line.

Comment: So you're not looking for the data to be re-organized to the top of the row, but you want your table to physically scroll to the row that matches the search?

Comment: yeah but no visible scroll, more like a direct jump

Comment: Perhaps look into getting the indexOf the query and then splice the array based on the index. could be you best bet so that your search query is the first in the list, followed by the rest of the data. Or you could even filter the query and unshift it back to the top.